# java.io.BufferedReader.readLine() consuming 99% CPU Why?

Tags: java, streaming

In this code i am reading a value from stream. But readline() method is taking more CPU.Can you help me why is this so and give me suggession to minimize CPU usage.

```
    HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    request.setRequestMethod("POST");
    request.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
    request.setUseCaches(false);

    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent());
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(in);  

    while(line = buff.readLine() != null) {
   System.out.print("hello");
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want your program to run slower?

Comment: *"Consuming 99% CPU"* for how long?

Comment: from when i start my application and it consume CPU 99% until i close my application

Comment: Have you tried `jstack` to see where you have the issue?

Comment: I prefer `jvisualvm` when I run into performance issue.

Comment: This code does not compile. What's the real code?

Comment: Does it behave like that for all URLs?

Comment: @johnchen902 If you have a gross performance like this, `jstack` (or more likely `ctrl-break` or whatever it happens to be on your platform) is typically sufficient.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin... can you give some idea about jstack? how can i use it ?

Comment: @Yogesh Run `jps` to find the process id. Then just run `jstack` with that process id as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be attaching the BufferedReader to the input stream of the request, but I find it hard to believe the statement in your title.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the print statement is the reason for the high cpu load. What happens if you remove it?